# How to prevent creation of mock objects to run static inits?

Tags: java, junit, mocking

Given this code:

```
class Booh {
  final static Booh throwUp = new Booh();
  Booh() { throw new RuntimeException("I didn't see that one coming"); }
}
```

And a test using Mokito.mock():

```
@Test 
public void testBooh() {
    Booh booh;
    booh = mock(Booh.class);
  }
}
```

I end up with:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.ensureError(J9VMInternals.java:137)
>       at java.lang.J9VMInternals.recordInitializationFailure(J9VMInternals.java:126)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor12.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:436)
>       at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:56)
>       at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:128)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:63)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:56)
>       at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:23)
>       at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:26)
>       at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:51)
>       at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1243)
>       at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1120)
>       at my.test.Class.testBooh(my.test.Class.java:162)
>       ....

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: I didn't see that one coming
...

Simple question: are there any means how I could prevent that exception; without changing the production code to avoid that static init thing?

( the above code is a mcve; in reality, things are more complicated, but in the end our problem is that unit test code tries to mock a class ... and that causes a ton of **static** finals to be init'ed; and some those init statements throws up in our unit test environment).

For the record: this is not a Mokito problem, I run into the same issue using EasyMock for example.

Comment: See my update - even when I declare a Booh **before** the mocking step, the exception is thrown for the mock() call line.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question: you can't load that class at all, irrespective of mocking. So how can it be used in production code? Or, are you asking how to stop you being able to mock it?

Comment: `Booh booh;` doesn't cause the class to be loaded. Try `System.out.println(Booh.throwUp);` before the `mock` line.

Comment: Apparently in PowerMock there is an annotation `@SuppressStaticInitializationFor(classname)`. Maybe this could help you? See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35054166/1744230) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29674083/1744230) answer.

Comment: @QBrute Probably that would help, but we have a strict "no powermock" policy over here.

Comment: One solution is to mock the class with JMockit: `@Test public void testBooh(@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization = true) Booh booh) { ... }`. Apart from that, you would either have to use some other bytecode manipulation tool (AspectJ, JBoss AOP, JBoss Byteman) or fix the actual production class which is failing during static initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to mock the class with JMockit:

```
@Test
public void testBooh(@Mocked(stubOutClassInitialization = true) Booh booh) {
    ...
}
```

(By default, `stubOutClassInitialization` is `false` because stubbing out the static initializers of a class means any `static final` fields will remain uninitialized until the end of the test run, as the JVM only performs static initialization *once* per loaded class.)

Apart from that, you would either have to use some other bytecode manipulation tool (AspectJ, JBoss AOP, JBoss Byteman) or fix the actual production class which is failing during static initialization.